# Display Lengths of Line in Matplotlib 3D Scatter

Tags: python, matplotlib, annotations, geometry, label

EDIT: fixed the xyz limits for axes with last 4 lines of code
Now, I just need the answer to displaying line length.

OK This will be a long question.  I'd like to (1)display the length of lines from center point to outlying points and (2)fix the axis coordinates to have a containing box of x-axis from 0-6, y-axis 0-6 and z-axis 0-6.

Here's the code so far.  I finally got the geometry right, but it looks all messed up because of the default adjusted containing box.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math as m

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')


x = [1, 5, 3, 3]
y = [1, 1, 1+(2* m.sqrt(3)), 1 +(2/3)*m.sqrt(3)]
z = [0, 0, 0, 4* m.sqrt(2)/m.sqrt(3)]

a = []
b = []
c = []
for item in x:
    a.append(float(item))
for item in y:
    b.append(float(item))
for item in z:
    c.append(float(item))

r = np.array(a)
s = np.array(b)
t = np.array(c)

ax.set_xlabel("x axis")
ax.set_ylabel("y axis")
ax.set_zlabel("z axis")


ax.scatter(r,s,zs = t, s=200)

for x, y, z in zip(r, s, t):
    ax.plot3D([x, 3], [y, 1+(2*(3**(1/2))/3)], [z, 4*(2**(1/2))/(3*(3**(1/2)))], 'b')

ax.set_ylim([0,6]). ##EDITED FIX TO AXES LABEL PROBLEM
ax.set_xlim([6,0])
ax.set_zlim([0,6])

plt.show()
```

Looks like this: (red text added afterwards and is what I'd like the changes to look like)

[image]

Comment: Can you post the code of the figure in the question?

Comment: try to make a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hopefully the edit makes sense.

Comment: change the way you do the arrays. Simply use: `np.array(x, dtype=np.float)` . Why is there a 6 in red at 3.5 z-axis? And those of the y axis are in reverse. Are you sure the problem is not the prospect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to display the length of the line, you need to first calculate this length by computing the (euclidean) distance between its end points in 3D space.
You can then put a text label (see [definition here](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.text)) to the plot, using `ax.text(x,y,z, text, ...)`, as shown e.g. in the [matplotlib demo page](http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/text3d_demo.html).

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math as m

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

r = np.array([1., 5., 3., 3.])
s = np.array([1., 1., 1.+(2* m.sqrt(3)), 1. +(2./3.)*m.sqrt(3)])
t = np.array([0., 0., 0., 4.* m.sqrt(2)/m.sqrt(3)])

ax.set_xlabel("x axis")
ax.set_ylabel("y axis")
ax.set_zlabel("z axis")

tx = "The line is {:.2f} units long."

ax.scatter(r,s,zs = t, s=200)

for x, y, z in zip(r, s, t):
    X = np.array([x, 3.])
    Y = np.array( [y, 1.+(2.*(3**(1/2.))/3.)])
    Z = np.array([z, 4.*(2**(1/2.))/(3.*(3.**(1/2.)))])
    # calculate length of line
    l = np.sqrt( np.diff(X)**2+np.diff(Y)**2+np.diff(Z)**2)
    ax.plot3D(X, Y, Z, 'b')
    # label the lines with the anchor at each line's center
    ax.text(X.mean(), Y.mean(), Z.mean(), tx.format(l[0]), size=10,color="r")

ax.set_ylim([0,6])
ax.set_xlim([6,0])
ax.set_zlim([0,6])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Worked great! Thanks.  Last note, I finally got the coordinates right too:  x = [1, 5, 3, 3, 3]
y = [1, 1, 1+(2* m.sqrt(3)), 1 +(2/3)*m.sqrt(3), 1 +(2/3)*m.sqrt(3)]
z = [0, 0, 0, 4* m.sqrt(6)/12, (4* m.sqrt(6))/3] . That is the x,y,z for the 4 vertices of a tetrahedron in 3D plus a point inside the pyramid, equidistant from each of the vertices.  Also, the molecular structure of Methane(and others), which is why I set out on this journey.  Thanks for your help and @Ibellomo 's

Comment: Could you please explain the math... namely - l = np.sqrt( np.diff(X)**2+np.diff(Y)**2+np.diff(Z)**2)
    ax.plot3D(X, Y, Z, 'b')

Comment: `l = np.sqrt( np.diff(X)**2+np.diff(Y)**2+np.diff(Z)**2)` gives you the length of the line, see [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance). If you want it's like Pythagoras for 3D.