# How to plot a plane perpendicular to a given normal and position in 3D in matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib

For example,
Let A be the x,y,z coordinate positions and N_A be the normal.
I need to plot a plane perpendicular to the normal with the normal arrow pointing in 3D

```
A = [0.960396491, 0.06136547597, -6.718505E-5]
N_A = [ -0.89169092,  0.02074738, -0.45216906]
```

Comment: Have you looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41578464/display-lengths-of-line-in-matplotlib-3d-scatter)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `plot_surface` method allows you to plot a surface given `xx`, `yy`, `zz` meshes. So the name of the game is creating these `meshgrid` objects.

A normal `(a, b, c)` specifies a plane via the relationship: `ax + by + cz + d = 0`, where we can determine `d` given a point `(x, y, z)` on the plane through simple arithmetic. Given arbitrarily chosen `xx` and `yy` `meshgrid` objects, we can then solve for `z` to compute the corrsponding `zz` `meshgrid`, and plot.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

point  = np.array([ 0.960396491, 0.06136547597, -6.718505E-5])
normal = np.array([-0.891690920, 0.02074738000, -0.45216906])

# A plane is given by
# a*x + b*y + c*z + d = 0
# where (a, b, c) is the normal.
# If the point (x, y, z) lies on the plane, then solving for d yield:
# d = -(a*x + b*y + c*z)
d = -np.sum(normal * point)

# Create a meshgrid:
delta = 5
xlim = point[0] - delta, point[0] + delta
ylim = point[1] - delta, point[1] + delta
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(*xlim), np.arange(*ylim))

# Solving the equation above for z:
# z = -(a*x + b*y +d) / c
zz = -(normal[0] * xx + normal[1] * yy + d) / normal[2]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(xx, yy, zz, alpha=0.5)

# Plot point.
x, y, z = point
ax.plot(x, y, z, marker='o', markersize=10, color='red')

# Plot normal.
dx, dy, dz = delta * normal
ax.quiver(x, y, z, dx, dy, dz, arrow_length_ratio=0.15, linewidth=3, color='red')

# Enforce equal axis aspects so that the normal also appears to be normal.
ax.set_xlim(*xlim)
ax.set_ylim(*ylim)
zlim = point[2] - delta, point[2] + delta
ax.set_zlim(*zlim)

# Label axes.
ax.set_xlabel('X', fontsize=20)
ax.set_ylabel('Y', fontsize=20)
ax.set_zlabel('Z', fontsize=20)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need to display the normal line with arrow to the plane. The normal's positions should be in the middle of the plane. I mean the A vectors are the 3d position of the normal arrow's position. Can you help me on that? 
My task is to create several of such planes. So I will have several normal vectors and planes. So the origin of the normal vector arrows to be in the center of the plane or let's say they are linked together is quite helpful.